# Is it ok not to use reject in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Is it allright to construct a Promise that never rejects? I mean is this some sort of anti-pattern or is it acceptable? Let me illustrate this with an example. I have a class ModifyURL that consits of many methods each method does something with an array of URI strings and returns a Promise. Part of implementation looks like this.

```js
class ModifyURL {
    constructor() {

    }
    /**
     * Remove empty and invalid urls
     * @param {object} object containing arrays of links
     *
     * @return {object} object containing arrays of valid links
     */
    removeInvalid(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            for (let key in data) {
                data[key] = data[key].filter( function(item) {
                    return !(item == '#' || !item || item == ' ');
                });
            }
            resolve(data)
        });
    }

    /**
     * Remove duplicates
     * @param {object} object containing arrays of links
     *
     * @return {object} object containing arrays of unique links
     */
    removeDuplicates(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            for (let key in data) {
                data[key] = data[key].filter(function (item, pos) {
                    return data[key].indexOf(item) == pos;
                })
            }
            resolve(data)
        });
    }
    /**
     * Add full hostname to relative urls.
     * @param {object}  object containing arrays of links
     * @param {string} hostname to be added if link is relative
     *
     * @return  {object} object containing arrays of absolute links
     */
    fixRelativeLinks(data,hostname) {
        if(typeof data === 'object'){
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                for (let key in data) {
                    data[key].forEach((v, i) => {
                        if(data[key][i]){
                            data[key][i] = URL.resolve(hostname, data[key][i])
                        }
                    })
                }
                resolve(data)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Later I chain these Promises and it works fine.

```js
                            modifyURL.removeInvalid(data).then(res=>{
                                return res
                            })
                            .then(()=>{
                                return modifyURL.fixRelativeLinks(data, res.request.href)
                            })
                            .then(modifyURL.removeDuplicates).then(res=>{
                                onSuccess(res)
                            }).catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
```

As you noticed I don't use **reject** and it feels a bit odd. The reason for that is that at the end I need to receive some data. Even if some **Promise** in chain fails to do their task I need to finally **resolve** with my array of URI strings. That's why I don't **reject** because it breaks my **Promise** chain. But without the **reject** I lose the ability to track errors propperly. What is the proper way to handle this kind of task?

Comment: What's the point of promises if you never do anything async inside? This manner of wrapping everything in promises looks bad to me.

Comment: if your code is sync, keep it as a function instead of a promise; you can still chain the results in a promise chain, and you can use it as a normal function as well.

Comment: Ok so that is wrong use of Promises. My bad. But let's assume these methods are async. For example they make API calls to geolocate the IP addresses of the websites. Would it be ok not to reject in order to keep Promise chain working?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that you're not doing anything asynchronous, if the `Promise` constructor's executor function (the function that accepts the `resolve` and `reject` parameters) throws an error, the constructed promise implicitly transitions to a rejected state, so you're fine. But if there are errors that can occur that don't throw, or promise chains created within the constructor that call back asynchronously, you'll need to check those conditions and call `reject()` with your own user-defined errors. In fact, if you have any promises inside your constructor, you shouldn't be using one.

Comment: @przemoo83 No, it would not be ok. If the API or the network fails, you definitely should reject the promise. Otherwise your caller will never be able to handle the error.

Comment: @przemoo83 What exactly do you mean by "*keep Promise chain working*"? Can you make an example for that? You should just use `.catch(e => substituteResult)` in the middle of a chain, which returns a fresh new promise that fulfills with the substitute result even if the previous promise failed.

Comment: @Bergi - it seems like a rookie problem but that's probably what I was missing:) In other terms I wanted to reslove with the data even if all Promises in chain failed to resolve. That seems to be the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it allright to construct a Promise that never rejects?

Yes, its all right.  If there is no possible error in the operation, then it's perfectly fine if the promise only resolves.

> I mean is this some sort of anti-pattern or is it acceptable?

It is perfectly acceptable to have a promise that never rejects (assuming there is some code path that it will resolve).  For example, you might write a function that resolves a promise after a particular delay such as this:

```
function delay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t, v);
    });
}
```

> I have a class ModifyURL that consits of many methods each method does something with an array of URI strings and returns a Promise. Part of implementation looks like this.

These are all synchronous functions.  They do not need to be wrapped in promises and should not be wrapped in promises.  Promises are for tracking asynchronous operations.  They only create more complicated code than necessary when using them with purely synchronous code.

While one can wrap synchronous operations with promises (as you have), I would call that an anti-pattern as it makes the code a lot more complex than just using normal synchronous coding patterns where you just call multiple functions one after another or if they all operate on the same data, make those functions all methods on an object and call them one after the other.

> As you noticed I don't use reject and it feels a bit odd. The reason for that is that at the end I need to receive some data.

First off, you're misusing promises here with synchronous code.  But, generically with asynchronous code, your code gets to decide what happens when there's an error.  You can let a rejection propagate and stop the chain or you can catch the rejection locally and change it into whatever you want the chain to continue with and the chain will not know any error occurred.  That's up to you and your code.  You are in full control of that.

> Even if some Promise in chain fails to do their task I need to finally resolve with my array of URI strings.

This is just about having proper local error handling so you catch and handle any error locally so you can continue processing the rest of your data and return the data that was successfully processed.  This would be no different in concept than using a `try/catch` with synchronous code to catch errors locally so you can catch them, handle them however is appropriate and continue with the rest of the work.

> That's why I don't reject because it breaks my Promise chain. But without the reject I lose the ability to track errors properly. What is the proper way to handle this kind of task?

There isn't really a generic answer to this as it really depends upon the particular application and what it's doing and how you want to communicate back both results and errors.  Sometimes you abort the chain upon first error (fail fast).  Sometimes you skip the errors and just return the successful results.  Sometimes you return an array of results and an array of errors.  Sometimes you return a single array that has both results and errors and you provide some means in the format of the data to know which is an error and which is a successful result.  And, you could invent as many other ways as you want to communicate back both results and errors.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed and comprehensive answers. You clarified the very issue I had trouble understanding. Of course the example I provided was a complete misuse of Promise mechanism and thank you for pointing that out as well.